# What is the effect of git add dirname/*

Tags: git, magento, github

I lost my app and skin folders from Magento after running git commands.

Here is my order of git commands:

```
git init
git add app/*
git add skin/* 
git remote add repulr  
git pull origin master  # (repo has git ignore with default magento
                        # github .gitignore file and readme)
git commit - m"adding only app and skin folder"
```

After running the above commands, it says that there is nothing to commit and there were no app and skin folders.

Can any one please explain what did I do wrong here and how can I get back my app and skin folders?

Comment: I think I should push remote changes to repo first. Here is the correct way for an existing code. 

git init (on server,where my code is located)
git remote add origin repourl
git push origin master

is that right ?

Comment: `git add [location]` will track all the files in the location.  Doesn't mean there are necessarily any changes after this command.

Comment: You shouldn't have done a `pull` before committing the stuff that you added.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the [e]ffect of `git add dirname/*` ?

It tells git to track all the files rooted in dirname, recursively including all the files in the subdirectories. The `/*` is redundant and you can simply say `git add dirname`.

```
git init && git add app && git add skin;
git pull origin master
git commit - m"adding only app and skin folder"

After running above commands, it says that nothing to commit and there
were not app and skin folders
```

Your recollection of the events might not be full, this is also evident from the fact that the quoted

```
git commit – m"..."
```

is an invalid git command with respect to the pathspec. But to your question, when you run `git pull` it **cannot** overwrite the files you added locally without explicitly telling you:

> The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge. 
> ...
>  Please move or remove
>   them before you can merge.

and you have to explicitly commit or drop your changes for the pull to proceed.

Comment: Thank you for reply. This is why I was shocked, even if I pull before push, it should ask me about override. anayway, I had a backup and every thing is fine now.